# re.findall to get a list directories from a /-separated pathname, but allowing // as a literal, single /

Tags: python, python-re

The title pretty much says it.

I tried a variety of things, including but not limited to:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(/+)([^/]*)', '///a//b/c///d')
[('///', 'a'), ('//', 'b'), ('/', 'c'), ('///', 'd')]
```

And:

```
>>> re.findall('(/+[^/]*)', '///a//b/c///d')
['///a', '//b', '/c', '///d']
```

What I want is something like:

```
>>> re.findall(something, '///a//b/c///d')
['/', 'a/b', 'c/', 'd']
```

...or close to that.  Note that this example is of a relative path, because the // at the beginning is a single slash comprising the entire first folder name.

We have something working using string.split('/') and list operations, but we want to explore regex-based solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Use raw strings `r''` for regex ([third paragraph in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)). This helps future-proof when you do add backslashes to escape things. I'm not sure I understand the logic of your second output. Can you explain why the first slash is alone, then there's `a/b`, then `c//`, then `d`? I don't see a pattern here.

Comment: The goal is to have a posix-like pathname, divided up into directories.  The main difference is we need to allow slashes in pathnames.  These are specified with a double-slash.

Comment: Why is the result for `c///d` supposed to be `c/`, `d`?  Why would `c`, `/d` not be a valid decoding?  How would you actually encode `/d` in this scheme, other than as the first element?

Comment: The // check is the greedy part.  They're both reasonable interpretations though.  /d would be an absolute path.

Comment: Note that `//` is allowed, on UNIX systems, to have special meaning to the filesystem. There are real filesystems in production today that do this -- look at AFS for an example. So it's not necessarily a good idea to overload it yourself.

Comment: Your escaping strategy is ambiguous.  How would you distinguish between `///` meaning `separator + /` or `/ + separator` ?  for example `c///d` could mean `["c","/d"]` or `["c/","d"]`  (I don't see how you get to `["c//","d"]` however).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Although this resembles a POSIX filesystem, it isn't one.  We're creating our own sort of filestore.

Comment: @AlainT. I know it's ambiguous.  That's why I said // is greedy and a lone / isn't.

Comment: I understand but that means it will be impossible to encode "/d" (or anything starting with a /) except as the first element of the list because the leading / would always be decoded as a suffix of the preceding element. (I'm guessing that's probably not a concern for your use cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that escaping has precedence over splitting (i.e. '///' = '/' + separator), you could do it like this :

```
p = '///a//b/c///d'

import re # this is not the ideal tool for this kind of thing

# pattern splits '/' when it is preceded by '//' (escaped '/')
# or when it is not preceded by another '/'
# in both cases the '/' must not be followed by another '/'

pattern = r"((?<=\/\/)|(?<!\/))(?!.\/)\/"

# replace the separators by an end of line then split on it
# after unescaping the '//'

path = re.sub(pattern,"\n",p).replace("//","/").split("\n")

# or split and unescape (exclude empty parts generated by re.split)

path = [s.replace("//","/") for s in re.split(pattern,p) if s] 

print(path) # ['/', 'a/b', 'c/', 'd']
```

However a non-re solution will probably be more manageable:

```
path = [s.replace("\0","/") for s in p.replace("//","\0").split("/")]

# or

path = p.replace("//","\0").replace("/","\n").replace("\0","/").split("\n")

print(path) # ['/', 'a/b', 'c/', 'd']
```

Note: to obtain `["c//","d"]` you would need the source to be encoded as  `"c/////d"`

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about

```
re.findall(r'[^/]*/+[^/]*', '///a//b/c///d')
['///a', '//b', '/c', '///d']
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to treat your string as 3 distinct patterns, like:

```
re.findall(r'(^/|[^/]+//[^/]*|[^/]+$)', '///a//b/c///d')
```

outputs:

```
['/', 'a//b', 'c//', 'd']
```